# Log function solve for x

Tags: functions

The function is defined by $y=f(x)=3e^{{1\over3}x+1}$

Solve for $x$ in terms of $y$

My answer:

$$x={\ln({y\over3})-1\over3}$$

Is this the correct way to go about this question?

Update. Finding the inverse and range.

Would the inverse of this function be:

$$f^{-1}(x)=3(\ln({x\over3})-1)$$

and its domain $x>0$

Comment: Almost: your very last step is wrong. Can you find the error? (By the way, if you use `\ln` you’ll get $\ln$ instead of $ln$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost it is:

$$
x=3(\ln{(\frac{y}{3})}-1)
$$

You should have multiplied by $3$ in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are right. Just don't put the 3 in the denominator at last, multiply 3.